# For loop is related to an Array in the same way as recursion is related to Trees?

Tags: arrays, recursion, tree

I'm trying to improve my conceptual understanding of Recursion on Trees.
Would you say - For loop is related to an Array in the same way as recursion is related to Trees - is a good analogy?

If you want to search anything in the array, you can use a loop. If you want to search anything in the tree, you can use recursion.
In arrays, as we traverse more and more elements, we keep track of our results with variables. In Trees, we keep track of our results with return statements + parameters + variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is an over simplication.

A recursive algorithm can be used on arrays, and iterative algorithms can be used on trees.

Moreover, every recursive algorithm can be written as an iterative algorithm, by using a stack.

It is true that a recursive algorithm itself forms a recursion *tree*, as if it is visiting nodes in a tree, but the data it operates on does not have to be a tree. For instance, quick sort is typically implemented with recursion, but it sorts an array. The different partitions it identifies during the process can be imagined as nodes in a binary tree.

There are even iterative and recursive algorithms that neither work with a an array nor a tree, but just with one or two numbers. For instance, there are iterative and recursive algorithms to calculate the greatest common divisor of two given integers.